# Brown silt forming ontop of aquasoil?

Tags: aquarium, fish, aquatic-plants

I have a 55 gallon freshwater tank with ADA aquasoil and have noticed that the dirt has started to have some type of brown silt forming ontop of it. It's not spread throughout the entire tank, I assume it is some type of detritus but am wondering if anyone else has seen this in their tank before.

Here's a picture:
[image]

In the past, I haven't been putting very much food into the tank as it only had shrimp, snails, and otocinclus catfish which are all algae eaters.

Is this brown silt something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical, generally people will siphon most of it out . Part of water change maintenance. There are attachments for siphon hoses that will lift off the brown material and leave the sand, mostly.

Comment: Yes, I was worried about mixing up the dirt since it is a planted aquarium with substrate additives and whatnot. I just didn't know if it was some type of weird algae or not :)